# Can't quite figure out what's "next"

Tags: material-ui

There are discussions about ThemeManager in various places on the net, but I noticed that it's only available in the react-native branch. Seems that it's not in the "next" release. Is this by omission or on purpose?
Thanks
Andy

Comment: [material-ui-template project](https://github.com/lmaccherone/material-ui-template) shows how to use ThemeManager. This [material-ui project](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) is what I am talking about. Looks like my question was not properly "linked to the project".

Answer (score 0):

The ThemeManager component was deprecated starting in v0.15.0 and was functionally replaced by the MuiThemeProvider component.

(source: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/690cbb4c905a98a5fb50dc9557c87f8ef6807842/CHANGELOG.md#0150-alpha1)